# postgresql order by from result of other query

Tags: postgresql

I have this two query.This is my first query:

```
SELECT 
    ss.id ss_number
    FROM sales_sourcing ss
    WHERE ss.state NOT IN ('draft','cancel')
    AND ss.source_type = 'import'
```

This is my seccond query:

```
SELECT write_date FROM sales_sourcing_chat ORDER BY create_date DESC
```

The relation is that the ss.id = chat_id
What I'm trying to do is to order the first query base on the order of the latest write_date from second query.

Comment: Have you tried to join your tables?

Answer (score 1):

As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75468613/postgresql-order-by-from-result-of-other-query#comment133156705_75468613) by Arkhena, it looks like you want to join them

```sql
SELECT ss.id ss_number
FROM sales_sourcing ss join sales_sourcing_chat ssc 
                        on  ss.id = ssc.chat_id
WHERE ss.state NOT IN ('draft','cancel')
AND   ss.source_type = 'import'
ORDER BY ssc.create_date desc, 
         ssc.write_date  desc;
```

You might want to clarify if that's the order you aimed for. After all, you're trying to order by `write_date` values that are themselves ordered by `create_date`.